# AngularJS $resource request, withCredentials with username and password

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, ngresource

I'm trying to do a small application that should fetch json data from a homepage with basic http authentication.

This is my service:

```
app.factory('MySrvs', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return $resource("http://address/to/json/document");

}]);
```

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'MySrcvs', 'Base64',
function($scope, MySrvs, Base64) 
var stuff =  MySrvs.query(function(data){
   console.log(data)
   $scope.mylist = data;
});
```

This works good for my mirrored page without auth.

However, the production should go to a page that needs `withCredentials:true` with username and password to set up. Where should this be added? I have access to a Base64 encoder.

Gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $resource configuration object is very similar to the $http configuration object (with a few
changes).
The value of the object, the action, is the name of the method on the resource object

for example

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('UserService', [
        '$resource', function($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/users/:id', {
                id: '@'
            }, {
                query: {
                    method: 'PUT', // or something else 
                    headers:{'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='} 
                }
            });
        }]);
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for how to do a query with $resource. What should the method be? GET? And where should I put the credentials? Username and password?

Comment: the method depends on your API

Comment: its a simple http auth using basic. I want to add for example this to the header: 'Authorization: Basic aHR0cHdhdGNoOmY='

Comment: I've updated example, I hope that should work , if not please try {'Authorization Basic': 'QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}

Comment: thanks, looks like a bug in chrome. works in firefox.

Comment: what happens can I help ?

Comment: Yes, you have helped. To the point where the server doesn't let me to CORS request. Thanks for the help. Regarding the withCredentials, I read that there is a bug in Chrome that doesn't trigger the credential box.